# calling the nested function through its address after the containing function has exited?

Tags: c

I get this question from this chinese
blog http://chenyufei.info/blog/2011-02-28/wrap-c-function-closure-gcc-nested-function/
The author want to use closure in c language, and he found GCC has the
ability of nested function (and closure).
**For example**:

```
typedef int (*func_t)(int arg);

 func_t create_wrap_function(func_t f) {

     int wrapped(int arg) {

         // call original function
         int val = f(arg);

         fprintf(log_func_call, "arg: %d ret: %d", arg, val);

         return val;
     }
     return wrapped;

 }
```

You shouldn't do this, at least according to the GCC docs:

"**If you try to call the nested function through its address after the
containing function has exited, all hell will break loose**."

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.5.2/gcc/Nested-Functions.html

Comment: What is your question?  Do you want to know whether the blogger is correct to disregard the warnings that come with this gcc extension?

Comment: @simonc yes, exactly what my question is .

Comment: You should just use blocks. This kind of hack is good for old C programs, but modern objective-C has better tools.

Comment: For real-world code, I would go with the compiler docs.  If you are just playing around for fun, then go ahead and see what you c an get away with.

Comment: @grasGendarme I don't think the OP has mentioned objective-C

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala My bad I tought I was browsing the objc flag. Sorry. (if you only target OS X you can use blocks in C code)

Answer (score 3):

The example cannot work (except by accident); the GCC-generated code in `wrapped()` accesses the parameter `f` via a register that would be set up when `create_wrap_function()` were to call `wrapped()`; when called from outside, this register isn't set, and the parameter `f` doesn't exist any more anyway.

Comment: Not to mention if the authors of the compiler tells you not to do this, it's probably good advice. They likely know more than you how this works, whether there's additional issues on certain platforms, with certain compiler flags, and whether they might change how it works in the next minor version of the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that closure is possible in C. It doesn't agree well with its stack using model. But you can call nested function by address as it is just a piece of code, so the code might run into it and then fail with segmentation fault or something. Have you tried going through this code step-by-steb with a debuger?